# convert rows to string in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Table name is `t1`. Field name is `name1`. name1 has value like this

```
-------------------------------------------+
+       name1                              +
--------------------------------------------
|    "a_2013,AcMaster,Master"              |
|   "b_2014,AcMaster,Master"               |
|   "c_2013,a_AcMaster,a_Master"           |
|    "d_2014,a_AcMaster,a_Master"          |
|__________________________________________|
```

But i want to get reslut like this

```
  master          acmaster               text
   Master          AcMaster                a_2013,b_2014
   a_Master        a_Master                c_2013,d_2014
```

So i try like this

```
    select (string_to_array(schemaname,',')) [3] as master,(string_to_array(schemaname,','))
 [2] as acmaster,(string_to_array(schemaname,',')) [1] from appsetup.company2 
c2,appsetup.company1 c1,appsetup.companygroup cg where    c1.compno=c2.compno and 
cg.compgroupno=c1.compgroupno and c1.compno in (3,2) group by 
string_to_array(schemaname,',')) [3],
(string_to_array(schemaname,',')) [2],cg.compgroupno,schemaname order by 
cg.compgroupno
```

But its return

```
master          acmaster               text
   Master          AcMaster              ["a_2013","b_2014"]
   a_Master        a_Master              ["c_2013","d_2014"]
```

How to get my wanted result?

Am using **Postgresql 9.3**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select string_agg(name1, ',') as Name1s
from t1
```

[string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

Comment: In case your column type to aggregate is not text, you need to add type cast:
`select string_agg(name1::text, ',') as Name1s from t1`